# Rails 4 form data saving nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm not getting any errors but when I check console, my data is saving as "nil". I have a user model set up using sorcery which is working fine. This model isn't though for some reason.

version_controller.rb

```
def create
  @version = Version.new(creation_params)

  if @version.save
    flash[:success] = "Version saved."
    redirect_to @version
  else
    render :new
  end
end

private

  def creation_params
    params.permit(:name, :description, :code)
  end
```

ui_controller.rb

```
def ui
  @versions = Version.all
  @version = Version.new
end
```

version.rb

```
class Version < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

ui.html

```
<%= form_for(@version) do |f| %>        
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :description %>
  <%= f.text_field :code %>
  <%= f.submit "Save Version" %>
<% end %>
```

routes.rb

```
resources :versions
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the strong parameter as

```
private

  def creation_params
    params.require(:version).permit(:name, :description, :code)
  end
```

Hope it will work

Comment: Tried that before and it didn't work. It worked now though. I restarted my server before I refreshed, maybe that was what was wrong.